# Nativescript :bindingContext to ListView

Tags: android, listview, nativescript

I am new to Nativescript and trying to develop an android app.I am sending a GET request and from the response I have built a Listview.Now,I am trying to send a POST request when a item of Listview is selected.But I can not bind the context.So,my POST request is not properly working.My question is how can I bind the context of listview.

Js Controller:

```
var CategoryViewModel = require("../../shared/category_view_model");

var fetchModule = require("fetch");

var dialogsModule = require("ui/dialogs");

var observableModule = require("data/observable")

var page;

var data;

var categoryList = new CategoryViewModel([]);  
var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    categoryList: categoryList
});



var UserViewModel = require("../../shared/brand_view_model");
var user = new UserViewModel();



exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;

    page.bindingContext = pageData;

    categoryList.empty();
    categoryList.load();


};

function getBrand() {

 user.register();

}
exports.brand=function (args) {


    getBrand();
}
```

View:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ categoryList }}" itemTap="brand">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ category }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"  />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

View-model for POST request:

```
var fetchModule = require("fetch");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

 var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
 var goodsList = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
 var pageData = require("data/observable").Observable;




function user(info) {
    info = info || {};

    // You can add properties to observables on creation
    var viewModel = new Observable({
        category: info.category || "",

    });

    viewModel.register = function() {



    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/user_signup", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 


    category:  viewModel.get("category"), 


    })
}).then(r => { return r.json(); }).then(function (r) {
     console.log("Success");
}, function (e) {
         console.log("Error occurred " + e);
    });


    };

         return viewModel;
}

    function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

module.exports = user;
```

Comment: Can you write what what context you got from function ? or what error if there is something ?

Comment: As you see,I don't bind the context for selecting the listview item.I don't know how.I already bind the context for creating listview in the exports.loaded function.But how to bind the context when a item is selected?And the error is,my data is saved in my server but it is blank.

Comment: quite possible as this line `;category:  viewModel.get("category")` from View-model is equal to `category:"",`  best would be pass item bindindContext to register function from tap event

Comment: please give a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it in this way

JS controller

```
exports.brand=function (args) {
    var list = args.object;
    var item = list.bindingContext; 
    user.register(item);
}
```

View model

```
viewModel.register = function(item) {
    //item points from user.register(item);
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/user_signup", {
       method: "POST",
       headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
       body: JSON.stringify({ 
          category:  item, 
       })
       }).then(r => { return r.json(); }).then(function (r) {
              console.log("Success");
       }, function (e) {
            console.log("Error occurred " + e);
       });
};
```

Comment: TypeError:Convertting circular structure to JSON.

Comment: didn't try event on tap of listview i copied and rewrite it for listview so wasn't sure if it will work but you can rewrite that it will be passing item based on index of array :) which should be easy to get that item

Comment: Yeah,your assumption worked well.But I want to get Label text.Can you help me with that?

Comment: for now with args.index it can be used as `categoryList[args.index].category` this should be same text as it would be at label inside tapped area i can write code for later around 4hours later as don't have time for that now to test out things from listview and even not sure if label can be done from tap event on item tap